# WCF service in a plugin architecture

Tags: c#, wcf, plugins

I'm trying to develop a WCF service that will expose loaded plugins.
Each plugin is present in a folder and will be loaded, in a dedicated Application domain, depending on client request.
My idea is briefly explained here below:

1. Create Interface IPlugIn in a shared library (shared between client and server)
2. Create abstract class PlugIn:IPlugIn (in the same shared library)
3. Each plugin library implements concrete class (inherited from PlugIn)
4. Plugin is loaded in a separate domain by the WCF service application when client asks for it (point 5)
5. Client sends the request IPlugIn GetPlugin(string pluginID) to the WCF service and use it

I developed till point 4 but i'm stuck with the GetPlugIn method (point 5) that is not able to serialize/deserialize the returned object.
what i need to do for making it working ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't serialize an interface - there's nothing to serialize.  You'll get back (at best) an object, which you'll have to cast to the correct concrete type.

Comment: Hi i'm not serializing an interface. I have abstract class, plugin inherit from that class. The WCF service has attribute         [ServiceKnownType(typeof(ServicePlugIn))].. i did it for other classes but this case is particular because the concrete class is created in an external assembly

Comment: `IPlugIn GetPlugin(string pluginID)` - based on the signature, it appears you are serializing an interface, hence my comment.  the method is returning `IPlugin` - you may actually be returning a concrete type that implements `IPlugin`, but I would expect the serializer to try and serialize the type specified, and it can't do that with an interface.

Comment: The following method works perfectly (the ServiceKnowType "tell" which concrete class must be used)

[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ServiceInfo))]
public IEnumerable<IServiceInfo> GetServices()
        {
            IEnumerable<IServiceInfo> services;
            try
            {
                return ServicesPlugInLoader.GetServices();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                HandleException(e);
                services = new List<IServiceInfo>();
            }
            return services;
        }